# How to do a custom app bar from large title to small with animation?

Tags: android, animation, android-actionbar, material-design, android-appbarlayout

I means this:

[image]

The transition occurs as the content on the layer begin to scroll.

It's similarly to `prominent` from [material.io](https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-top.html#anatomy). But I don't know how to do it. I could not find an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Introduce

This is implemented by `View`: `Toolbar` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout` inside `AppBarLayout`.

## Solution

New project -> Choose `Scrolling Activity` -> Next -> Finish

You will see similar `activity_main.xml`

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        style="@style/ToolbarTextAppearanceStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```